# PHP isset to change BGColor?

Tags: php

I'm currently using the following code to display text from a variable if it exists to display text:

```
<th class='techid tooltip' data-tech='".$row."' style=\"background:#CCC\">
    <span class='staffinfo ".$techHighLight."'>".$row."- ";
        echo 
            substr($record["EmpLastName"],0,10).(isset($record_StaffSetID) ? "(".$record_StaffSetID.")" : "")."
    </span>
</th>
```

I need to alter the background:#CCC so that if the isset is true it becomes background:#000.  I've tried a series of if/else and keep getting syntax errors.

Here is a snippet of what I've tried with no luck:

```
echo "<th class='techid tooltip' data-tech='".$row."' ".(isset($record_StaffSetID) ? "style=background:#000 !important;" : "style=background:#CCC !important;").">
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: The _immediate_ answer is: "use the ternary operator (see documentation for details)". The _constructive_ answer here should be: start using css classes and move your inline style definitions into separate css files to clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
<?php
if (isset($record_StaffSetID)) :
?>
<th class='techid tooltip' data-tech="<?php echo $row; ?>" style="background:#CCC">
    <span class='staffinfo <?php echo $row; ?>'>
      <?php echo $row ?> - 
      <?php echo substr($record["EmpLastName"],0,10).(isset($record_StaffSetID) ? "(".$record_StaffSetID.")" : ""); ?>
    </span>
</th>
<?php 
else:
?>
<th class='techid tooltip' data-tech="<?php echo $row ?>" style="background:#000">
    <span class='staffinfo <?php echo $techHighLight ?>'>
      <?php echo $row ?> - 
      <?php echo substr($record["EmpLastName"],0,10).(isset($record_StaffSetID) ? "(".$record_StaffSetID.")" : ""); ?>
    </span>
</th>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it is not really elegant !!

Comment: And for the record, I think it's as elegant as it needs to be!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also just assign a variable.

```
$bg_color = isset($record_StaffSetID) ? '#000' : '#CCC';
echo '<th class="techie tooltip" data-tech="'.$row.'" style="background-color:'.$bg_color.';">';
```